# About Android Studio and Flutter Inspector

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

So I normally use Flutter Inspector on a daily basis and lately, after some updates which I cannot distinguish, Flutter Inspector stopped working. Here's what I get when I open it:

Setting up DevTools Failed

[Error Setting up DevTools Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKMZ6.png)

It is probably related to some versioning, but I can't figure it out how to fix this. Here are my results for:

Flutter Doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.592], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

Notice that Doctor complains about the plugin in Android Studio, but it is actually installed and running. I can compile and run apps perfectly fine. It's just the inspector that doesn't work.

Flutter version

```
Flutter 1.22.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 84f3d28555 (3 weeks ago) • 2020-10-15 16:26:19 -0700
Engine • revision b8752bbfff
Tools • Dart 2.10.2
```

Android Studio

```
Android Studio 4.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 494M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.huawei.deveco.hms, Dart, io.flutter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flutter plugin of the IDE, is not compatible with the current version of the SDK, so it does not show you that error, you could change to the dev channel of the Flutter SDK.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Sharing a source with it would help us to narrow the issue. I couldn't find it :-(