# Setting up DevTools failed (Flutter Inspector)

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I could not find solution to this either on google or here on StackOverflow. There is only and only 1 question answered related to this issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64655867/about-android-studio-and-flutter-inspector], however for a beginner like me, its not clear about what exactly to do.

Additional information:

- OS: Windows
- Android studio version 4.1.1
- App is running in avd when I opened flutter inspector panel.
- Stopped and run the app again.
- Previously, somewhere I read that if inspector is not showing anything, click on any widget pressing ctrl key. That worked previously, but not working now. Sure, that was different error and different situation.
- flutter doctor screenshot also attached

[flutter inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj0dj.jpg)

[flutter doctor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZG2g.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

If you have the JCEF is not supported in this env or failed to initialize error, here is how you can fix it:

Go to Help -> Find action

Search and select "Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE"

In that popup, select a JetBrains runtime that has JCEF

Then restart the IDE and the error is gone.

Comment: This made me get the error "Too many restarts of GPU-process (JCEF)"

Comment: Found not by me, but at the Jetbrains issues tracking:

1. Select Find Action from the Help menu
2. Enter Registry and select Registry
3. Find the ide.browser.jcef.sandbox.enable option in the list that appears and disable it
4. Restart

Worked well for me

Answer (score 3):

This answer from related question helped.

> ...
> And the third one (the one that worked for me): go to File >
> Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter > Experiments … and there
> you should uncheck “Enable embedding DevTools in the Flutter Inspector
> tool window”. That should allow you to use devtools locally instead of
> the embedded ones.

[picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ2rG.png)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65542661/17789382

Answer (score 1):

Found not by me, but at the Jetbrains issues tracking:

1. Select Find Action from the Help menu
2. Enter Registry and select Registry
3. Find the ide.browser.jcef.sandbox.enable option in the list that appears and disable it
4. Restart

Worked well for me

Comment: a recent update fixed this issue - changing the registry entry should not be required anymore, but it indeed fixed the issue in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Flutter DevTools from terminal using command `dart devtools` which opens DevTools in the browser. Connect to the address in which debug/run service listening on. Address can be found in the console when the app starts running. Ex: `ws://127.0.0.1:54851/JF3H6rhQnN0=/ws`.

Answer (score -4):

The following steps helped me to get Flutter Inspector Widget Tree back, hopefully, it will help you as well:

1. File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter:
2. Enable (Check) "Open Flutter Inspector view on app launch"
3. Stop and start the app again.

Note: In order for something to show up in the Flutter Inspector, your app has to be running on a Device or on a Simulator or Emulator.